# These code snippets should be equivalent, what's wrong with it?

Tags: javascript, php

Here's the original PHP function that works correctly.

```
<?php
$const = [
    'mod_q' => gmp_init("12341234123412341234"),
    'jj_d'  => gmp_init("23452345234523452345"),
    'base00' => gmp_init("34563456345634563456"), 
    'base01' => gmp_init("45674567456745674567")];
function retc($key_bin, $mod_q_bin, $base){
    global $const;
    $ret0 = 0;
    $ret1 = 1;
    foreach(str_split($key_bin) as $c){
        for($j = 0; $j <= $c; $j++){
            $u2 = ($j == 1) ? $const["base{$base}0"] : $ret0;
            $v2 = ($j == 1) ? $const["base{$base}1"] : $ret1;
            $x = gmp_mod(gmp_mul($ret1, $v2), $const['mod_q']);
            $y = gmp_mod(gmp_mul($const['jj_d'], gmp_mod(gmp_mul($ret0, gmp_mod(gmp_mul($u2, $x), $const['mod_q'])), $const['mod_q'])), $const['mod_q']);
            $u3 = 1; 
            $v3 = 1;
            foreach(str_split($mod_q_bin) as $d) {
                $u3 = gmp_mod(gmp_mul($u3, $u3), $const['mod_q']);
                $v3 = gmp_mod(gmp_mul($v3, $v3), $const['mod_q']);
                if ($d == 1){
                    $u3 = gmp_mod(gmp_mul($u3, gmp_mod(gmp_add(1, $y), $const['mod_q'])), $const['mod_q']);
                    $v3 = gmp_mod(gmp_mul($v3, gmp_mod(gmp_sub(1, $y), $const['mod_q'])), $const['mod_q']);
                }
            }
            $u3 = gmp_mod(gmp_mul(gmp_mod(gmp_add(gmp_mod(gmp_mul($ret0, $v2), $const['mod_q']), gmp_mod(gmp_mul($ret1, $u2), $const['mod_q'])), $const['mod_q']), $u3), $const['mod_q']);
            $ret1 = gmp_mod(gmp_mul(gmp_mod(gmp_sub($x, gmp_mod(gmp_mul(-1, gmp_mod(gmp_mul($ret0, $u2), $const['mod_q'])), $const['mod_q'])), $const['mod_q']), $v3), $const['mod_q']);
            $ret0 = $u3;
        }
    }
    return [$ret0, $ret1];
}
```

This is a Javascript function that (besides for different variable name for global constants) is meant to be functionally identical, however there's an error.

```
const params = {
    mod_q : 12341234123412341234n,
    jj_d : 23452345234523452345n,
    base : [[34563456345634563456n, 
             45674567456745674567n]]};
function retc(key_bin, mod_q_bin, base){
    var ret = [0n, 1n];
    for(jj = 0; jj < key_bin.length; jj++){
        for(j = 0; j <= key_bin[jj]; j++){
            uv2 = ret;
            if(j == 1) uv2 = params['base'][base];
            x = (ret[1] * uv2[1]) % params['mod_q'];
            var y = (params['jj_d'] * ((ret[0] * ((uv2[0] * x) % params['mod_q'])) % params['mod_q'])) % params['mod_q'];
            var uv = [1n, 1n];
            for(var ii = 0; ii < mod_q_bin.length; ii++){
                uv[0] = (uv[0] ** 2n) % params['mod_q'];
                uv[1] = (uv[1] ** 2n) % params['mod_q'];
                if(mod_q_bin[ii] == '1'){
                    uv[0] = (uv[0] * ((1n + y) % params['mod_q'])) % params['mod_q'];
                    uv[1] = (uv[1] * ((1n - y) % params['mod_q'])) % params['mod_q'];
                } 
            }
            uv[0] = (((((ret[0] * uv2[1]) % params['mod_q']) + ((ret[1] * uv2[0]) % params['mod_q'])) % params['mod_q']) * uv[0]) % params['mod_q'];
            ret[1] = (((x - ((-1n * ((ret[0] * uv2[0]) % params['mod_q'])) % params['mod_q'])) % params['mod_q']) * uv[1]) % params['mod_q'];
            ret[0] = uv[0];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

To run either code snippet here's a sample function call; the output should be the same:

```
retc('0000110011000001000111001100110011100101000101100001101100110110111110100001010111111101110000101011000101000001110000101111110001010011101100111001111100111000100110111110101011110110100101001100100000010011011010010111110111101001011011100100001100101110', '0111001111101101101001110101001100101001100111010111110101001000001100110011100111011000000010000000100110100001110110000000010101010011101111011010010000000010111111111111111001011011111111101111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111111111111111111', 0);
```

This particular example the PHP function returns `[2960296029602960296, 4530453045304530453]` which would be correct and the Javascript function returns `[-9380938093809380938, -7810781078107810781]` which is incorrect.

I'm not sure if I'm just not understanding how the math behind it works but have been trying to fix it with no luck so any help appreciated.

Comment: @James the JavaScript code in the question uses JavaScript `BigInt` values.

Comment: @aynber they're `BigInt` constants.

Comment: One possible source of problems would be that the JavaScript `%` operator can return negative values.

Comment: @Pointy That sounds reasonable, all of the invalid outputs have been negative. Is that easily fixable or is it better to use a 3rd party BigInt JS library?

Comment: Nice to have some native BigInt support!  Hopefully will have full browser support soon.

Comment: Well you can take any expression `a % b` and if you think `a` might be negative, it's the same as `(a + b) % b`

Comment: Or alternatively, check for negative results and add the modulus if so.

Comment: you were right, works perfectly now. thank you :) if you post that as an answer i'll accept!